# Can I create subnets in a particular Availability Zone using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a subnet in `ap-south-1a` and the next subnet shall be in `ap-south-1b`. Can this be done? Please help me.

I tried creating subnets as we normally do in CF. Also I have given parameters for dropdown of list of availability zones.

```
Parameters:{
"Type":"AWS::EC2::AvailabilityZone::Name",
"Description": "AZ",
"Default": "-"

},
```

Expectation:
https://images.app.goo.gl/WozfoNLVEeBhDkVs9

I would be more than happy if I could understand how this thing works.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation Macros are an excellent way to add dynamic resources to your templates.

For general documentation on that topic, look at [AWS Macros](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html)

and for an example of what you are possibly trying to achieve, see

[Dynamically add subnets to VPC with CloudFormation Macros](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Public-and-Private-Subnet-per-AZ)

Be aware this *is* a somewhat advanced topic if you are just setting out on your CloudFormation adventure. CFN is beast that needs some taming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You'll just need to specify the availability zone for each subnet when defining them in CloudFormation.

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties" : {
    "AvailabilityZone" : "ap-south-1a",
    "CidrBlock" : "10.0.1.0/24",
    "Tags" : [ "Name": "10.0.1.0" ],
    "VpcId" : "vpc-afd99ac9"
  }
},
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties" : {
    "AvailabilityZone" : "ap-south-1b",
    "CidrBlock" : "10.0.2.0/24",
    "Tags" : [ "Name": "10.0.2.0" ],
    "VpcId" : "vpc-afd99ac9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want this to be dynamic, the way we create subnets in the AWS console, can this be done like that? I have already used the above method of assigning availability zones.

Comment: @prakashjha If you want it to be dynamic you can accept parameters into your cloudformation script for each individual subnet you want to create.

Comment: @prakashjha If you are looking to be able to create a dynamic number of subnets with distinct availability zones you could look into nested cloudformation stacks https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, will check with this.

Comment: @prakashjha I should also mention that the intention of CloudFormation is to create a static set of resources in order to ship a reproducible stack to employees and customers, so dynamically generating subnets inside of one is an anti-pattern and against best practice. If you want to set up something with a UI that is dynamic, I would recommend boto3 or some other SDK.

Comment: @asdf I'm sorry but I strongly beg to differ: the requirements to have dynamic resources and properties is what drove addition of things like CFN macros, as well as tools like Troposphere. On AWS examples sites you will find examples that do exactly what the OP is trying to do: use macros to dynamically create subnets in VPCs based on the variable number of AZs. See https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/tree/master/aws/services/CloudFormation/MacrosExamples/Public-and-Private-Subnet-per-AZ which is from AWS Labs themselves.

Comment: @Marakai Ah, I did not know about macros. It's been about a year since I've heavily used CloudFormation and it looks like those did not exist then (templates posted 4 months ago). I tried accomplishing something like OP said a while back and it felt like an anti-pattern then. Will upvote your answer for clarity